# Issue with PHP retrieving variables

Tags: php, html

I have a very normal form linking through to a simple php script within a html page on my site. It looks as follows

```
        <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" required="required" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" required="required" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email "id="email" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Here is sendemail.php (Where the form data is sent).
§
    'success',
            'message'=>'Email sent!'
        );

```
    $first_name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['first_name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $last_name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['last_name'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

    $subject = "A new ewnquiry from your website!";

    $email_from = "jackb@example.com";
    $email_to = 'jackb@example.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $first_name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;

    ?>
```

The email is sending through to the correct address and it shows the variables that have not been passed from the form ($subject).

But the variables from the form are not being passed through.

Can anyone help me to see where the issue lies with this please. I am new to the site.

Comment: *"The email is sending through to the correct address and it shows the variables that have not been passed from the form ($subject)."* - I for one, have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: 1) The email is arriving in the correct mailbox.

Comment: 2) The variables that are not passed from the html form work within the email ($subject for example)

3) The variables passed from the original form do not display in the email that arrives at the correct inbox.

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump` the `$_POST` array? Just to check if it's getting any values.

Comment: You might consider not posting your actual mail address in your question.

Comment: Get rid of all those `@`. If you're getting errors accessing the `POST` variables, the error messages are being hidden.

Comment: I've been staring at this question/comments for over 20 mins and I still don't know what the question's about *lol* - I guess I have too much time on my hands and don't know where to throw myself with this one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's simple; **mysterious** vars that are never set anywhere and being sent, but the ones in the form are not sent... (I think) Simples.

Comment: @Pogrindis Must be Goblins and/or Leprechauns.

Comment: never set anywhere......can you not just help me? no?....tell me what im doing wrong? :-/

Comment: @JackB try to re-phrase the question, maybe showing what the data is, and what you expect to see.. It's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['var1']) && !empty($_POST['var2']) && !empty($_POST['var3'])){...}` - etc. and suspecting you're using the entire code in the one file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm submitting this answer because it's the only thing that could come of having empty values, IF that's what the question's about.

IF... you have your entire code inside the same file being both the HTML form and PHP, then that would explain the empty values, which I suspect to be.

Therefore you need to check if any or all are left empty (or not).

So you need to do something like this and using a conditional `!empty()`:

By the way, you were using the wrong variable for `echo json_encode($status);` which should have been `$success` because that would have read as `null`.

```
if(!empty($_POST['first_name']) 
   && !empty($_POST['email']) 
   && !empty($_POST['last_name']) 
   && !empty($_POST['message'])
){

$first_name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['first_name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$last_name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['last_name'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

$subject = "A new ewnquiry from your website!";

$email_from = "email@example.com";
$email_to = 'email@example.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $first_name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($success);
die;

}
else{
    echo "Something was left empty.";
    }
```

This was successfully tested by the way.

You can replace the `&&` for `||` if you wish.

- `&&` => `AND`
- `||` => `OR`.

Comment: its a seperate php file. action="sendemail.php"

Comment: @JackB as I posted in my answer; tested successfully.

Comment: yeh well it doesnt actually do anything accept not send the script if they are empty. doesnt actually tell me why they vars arnt being passed to the script in the first place.